# Qual é o significado das palavras "contextualizar" e "síntese"?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

Estou lendo um texto que descreve uma atividade da minha faculdade, entretanto, uma parte deste texto me gerou uma confusão a respeito das palavras ***contextualizar*** e ***síntese***. E para uma melhor compreensão do que se trata a minha dúvida, segue o texto completo:

> **Contextualizar significa realizar uma síntese do domínio do Negócio**,
> ou mais especificamente o Setor de Negócio escolhido pelo grupo. Uma
> contextualização típica deve conter aproximadamente 2 páginas (para
> fins de propósito acadêmico, ou mais para uma aplicação real). Esses
> parágrafos ajudam no entendimento inicial do Sistema de Informação
> Computadorizado a ser desenvolvido. Nessa contextualização
> mencionam-se, sinteticamente, os principais Conceitos de interesse,
> representados por Funcionalidades (tarefas) e Regras de negócio. Aqui
> já podem ser identificados os Atores principais envolvidos.
> Saliente-se que as tarefas identificadas atendem tanto clientes
> internos quanto externos a empresa. Ao definir requisitos, se faz
> necessário definir as Necessidades de Informação do Negócio,
> considerando a pirâmide organizacional que estrutura hierarquicamente
> a empresa nos níveis Operacional, Tático e Estratégico.

Eu entendo que [contextualizar](https://www.dicio.com.br/contextualizar/) é mostrar as circunstancias que estão ao redor de um fato, e [síntese](https://www.dicio.com.br/sintese/) seria como um resumo de algo. Minhas dúvidas estão relacionadas ao significado dessas duas palavras.

---

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é o significado síntese?
2. O que é contextualizar?
3. Existe alguma relação entre contextualizar e síntese?

Comment: Os significados são esses mesmos que tu indicaste. Em geral *contextualizar* não significa 'fazer uma síntese', mas em casos concretos pode ser conveniente uma síntese para contextualizar algo. Imagina que tens um estudo de 100 páginas sobre o tal domínio de negócio. Para contextualizar alguma coisa tu poderás querer fazer uma síntese dessas 100 páginas. Não faço ideia se é isso que se passa no teu caso. Terias de contextualizar essa frase para se compreender o que ela significa; tal como está ela não faz sentido nenhum para mim. >>

Comment: Também em certos domínios as palavras adquirem significados especializados, que podem não vir nos dicionários gerais. Não sei se não será isso no teu caso.

Comment: @Jacinto compreendi. Pelo fato de buscar uma exatidão na palavra de maneira restrita não percebi que o significado da palavra pode mudar dependendo do domínio.

Comment: Gato, o que eu disse acima são especulações. Talvez vendo o texto completo pudesse fazer uma ideia mais exata. Mas por exemplo, o Instituto Nacional de Estatística (Portugal) publica uma [*Síntese Económica de Conjuntura*](https://www.ine.pt/xportal/xmain?xpid=INE&xpgid=ine_publicacoes&PUBLICACOEStipo=ea&PUBLICACOEStema=55529&selTab=tab0&xlang=pt). Aqui, *síntese* serve apenas para dar a ideia que a publicação contém apenas um resumo dos indicadores que o Instituto recolheu. >>

Comment: Talvez a chave no teu caso esteja na palavra "significa", que pode estar a ser usada inexatamente com o sentido de 'consiste em': "Contextualizar (no caso presente) consiste em..." Não podes falar com o autor do texto para esclarecer?

Comment: @Jacinto não sera possível falar com o autor do texto (professor) nessa semana, ele esta viajando. Se quiser, eu posso colocar o texto no corpo da pergunta? Não é um texto longo.

Comment: Gato, coloca. Assim o pessoal pode tentar ver melhor do que se trata.

Comment: @Jacinto pronto coloquei o texto.

Comment: Gato, vê lá se achas que fica melhor assim, evitando a repetição. Podes sempre voltar à versão anterior ou voltar a modificar à tua vontade.

Comment: @Jacinto ficou ótimo!

Comment: Se percebo bem, a tal contextualização tem por objetivo descrever o contexto em que o Sistema de Informação Computorizado vai operar. Ou seja, a ideia é: alguém vai desenvolver um Sistema de Informação Computorizado para um domínio de Negócio, e é necessário ter uma descrição desse domínio de negócio para orientar o desenvolvimento do sistema de informação de acordo com as necessidades e peculiaridades desse negócio. Será isso?

Comment: @Jacinto é neste ponto que minha dúvida me impede de prosseguir. Então seria uma descrição do ambiente onde o sistema iria atuar, e a contextualização descreve o **domínio de negócio**. Me parece ser isso.

Comment: @Jacinto eu não sei se é para **contextualizar** ou **sintetizar**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63459/discussion-between-jacinto-and-gato).

Comment: Contexto é o ambiente em que ocorrem. Síntese é como ocorrem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Contextualizar* e *síntese* significam o que já indicaste (já acrescentamos algo mais a *síntese*), e no meu entendimento a frase em destaque significa:

> **Contextualizar** [o Sistema de Informação Computorizado] **significa** [no caso presente] **realizar uma síntese** [dos dados relevantes sobre o] **domínio de negócio** [a que o Sistema se destina]

O que se passa na frase original é muito comum na comunicação: o locutor omite elementos relevantes—neste caso, os elementos entre colchetes—e normalmente o interlocutor supre as lacunas com o conhecimento que tem do locutor e do assunto em discussão. Neste caso eu supri-as com o resto do texto; o autor provavelmente esperaria que as lacunas pudessem ser preenchidas com que ele já tinha dito antes.

[*Contextualizar* (Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/contextualizar) é sempre contextualizar algo, isto é “apresentar as circunstâncias e o contexto de” algo. Neste caso o algo é o Sistema de Informação Computorizado. Queremos saber qual é o contexto, o ambiente, em que esse Sistema vai operar.

Nesta frase são relevantes as aceções 1 e 2 de [*síntese* no Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/s%C3%ADntese)

> **1.** Exposição geral e resumida (síntese do projeto).
>   **2.** Reunião de diversos elementos num todo coerente: *Esta proposta é uma síntese de todas as propostas feitas.*

Ou seja, queremos recolher os dados relevantes sobre o negócio e apresentá-los num todo coerente e conciso. Naturalmente nós sintetizamos os dados, não sintetizamos o próprio negócio, mas isto praticamente nem precisa de ser dito.